# grails g:select passing dynamic form elements as param

Tags: grails, groovy

I am running into an issue where by I want to pass form elemets that gets generated dynamically as such id's of those elements are dynamic as well.
Here is the code snippet I am running

```
<g:each in="${selectedList}" status="i" var="menuForCity">
<td><input type="checkbox" id="${100+i}" name="check_list" value="${city.id}" checked="checked" /></td>
    <g:select name="myClass.id"
                                              from="${instances}"
                                                onchange="${remoteFunction(
                                                controller:'cityPlan', 
                                                action:'test',
                                                params:'\'id=\'+this.value+\'\'&cityid=\'+document.getElementById(100+i).value',
                                                update:(i+1))}"
                                                optionKey="id" />
...
```

Problem I am running into is how to get id of dynamic checkbox thats created in the form ?
Is there any way I can write/evaluate gstring ?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
params:'\'id=\'+this.value+\'\'&cityid=\''+city.id,
update:(i+1))}"
optionKey="id" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not answering your question but there's an extra single quote in your code that shouldn't be there in the first place, that might solve your problem.

```
params:'\'id=\'+this.value+\'\'&cityid=\'+document.getElementById(100+i).value',
```

should be:

```
params:'\'id=\'+this.value+\'&cityid=\'+document.getElementById(100+i).value',
```